# Forecast() function in R: how it works?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a doubt related to the `forecast ()` function from the package Forecast.
I am using this function for forecasting the closing price of a stock given an ARIMAX model (with `xreg`). **The doubt is**: when it is forecasting, the closing price at time **t** depends on the external regressors at time **t-1** or it (closing price) depends on the external regressors at time **t**?
In other words, today I still don't know the high price (i.e.) so the closing price of today cannot depend on the high price of today, but on the one of yesterday.
This function works like that or in a different way?

I hope I have been clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can setup the function to work like this yes! Though there are some steps to take:

1. lag the regressor as you want yesterdays value to explain todays
2. clean values without regressor (first value of timeseries got no regressor as it will be used for the second value of the ts)
3. build the regressor for prediction
4. model and predict

Below I wrangled something together from a few links that shows how it can be done and thus should explain how prediction with regressor in your case works with forecast:

```
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

# get some finance data to play with
quantmod::getSymbols("AAPL", from = '2017-01-01',
                     to = "2018-03-01",warnings = FALSE,
                     auto.assign = TRUE)

# I prefer working with df and then convert to ts objects later
new_AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)%>%
    # select close values and lag high values
    dplyr::transmute(AAPL.Close,
                     AAPL.High = lag(AAPL.High)) %>%
    # keep only complete values
    dplyr::filter(across(everything(), ~!is.na(.x)))

# set up new time series, regressor (watch the starting points)
AAPL.Close <- ts(new_AAPL$AAPL.Close, start = as.Date("2017-01-04"), frequency = 365)
AAPL.High <- ts(new_AAPL$AAPL.High, start = as.Date("2017-01-04"), frequency = 365)

# set up the future regressor (last value of original high values
AAPL.futureg <- ts(as.data.frame(AAPL)$AAPL.High[291], start = as.Date("2018-03-02"), frequency = 365)

# I will use a arima model here
modArima <- forecast::auto.arima(AAPL.Close, xreg=AAPL.High)

# forecast with regressor
forecast::forecast(modArima, h = 1, xreg = AAPL.futureg)
```

Here is where I got the infos from:

https://www.codingfinance.com/post/2018-03-27-download-price/

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/how-to-setup-xreg-argument-in-auto-arima-in-r

Comment: @GDC if that is what you are looking for please consider to accept my answer for others to know it has been solved... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just need to clarify something. I lagged the xreg removing the latest value end inserting a row of zeros as first row (the oldest one). So assuming I have 640 observation I removed the 640th and added a new row at spot 1. But, something strange happens in the result. In fact the predicted result when I don't lag the xreg it is at time 1 $500 (i.e.), but when I lag the xreg at time 1 I have a different value but at time 2 I have $500 (the prediction just shift about 1 place from t=1 to t=2 and nothing changes at all). Can you help me? There is a way to do it in R?

Comment: @GDC after lagging you have to remove the first (aka. earliest or oldest) observation as there is not xreg value available (it went to the second aka second earliest observation). Replacing the generate NA in xreg with 0 will "confuse" your model (because your are supplying false information when imputing with 0). I do not know your data but it sounds like you did lag and not remove the last (aka latest or jungest) value of xreg which is in the future (consering the model) and thus should only be used in the forecast() function

Comment: @GDC maybe try to reproduce my code and then substitute the input (AAPL) with your data, using only one xreg variable (ajusting the starting dates, etc. acordingly)

Comment: Thanks. It seems I solved the issued by using the `shift()` function.

Comment: great - plz consider to accept or upvote my answer - we (who is answering) are here for the point we get when you accept or upvote... in case you do neighter I wont get anything for the effort: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: My feedback has been recorded but I need reputation points otherwise I cannot vote.

Comment: @GDC thx - just one recomendation with time series prediction for you to leverage maximum quality prediction: instead of predicting the closing value itself and running a model on the closing values, it is recomend to work with the diferences as model input and output. Meaning you run diff() on your values so that you use the spread between the days as input and predict the next diference (which you just have to add to yesterday closing value to get tomorrows closing value)... this way your model focusses exclusively on what you actually want and you reduce distractions

Comment: So, you suggest me to work with the returns of closing prices and not with the closing price itself? I am running `auto.arima(y, xreg= xreg, trace = TRUE)` where the y is my closing price in time series terms and the xreg are the exogenous regressors in matrix form (this for the train part).

Comment: @GDC if by "return of closing prices" you mean the diference compared to the prior time unit instead of the value ifself than yes. In R you would just use the diff() function on your variables => try it diff(c(1,2,3,4)) and look at the result <= ... as with the lagging you loose one observation (or one more) due to this process but it is recommened as you are looking to predict the change ... One of the links in the answer talks about this in the comments.

Comment: I actually have used the diff(log(closing_price)) to compute the returns. I have implemented the auto.arima having this variable and seems to be white noise and there is no autocorrelation. Is this the right approach? Because before I was working directly with the closing price without doing any manipulation on it. My objective is to do a prediction on the BTC price formation with exogenous variables

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/when-to-log-transform-a-time-series-before-fitting-an-arima-model

Comment: So it seems that if I use ARIMAX model I don't have to convert in stationary data because the I term already does it. So I should not differentiate (according to this). On the other hand, if I wanna use an ARMAX model I need to differentiate the Y because this model works with stationary data. Is it right?